# How to create Dax Measures in PowerBI to get delta from previous day

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is the matrix from PowerBI, row1 is the sales measure and row2 is the delta measure.
Trying to get the measure to see the delta in the matrix

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 110 | 130 |
| 0 | 10 | 20 |

Created below measure which is not working as expected,

```
Delta =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Fact'[sales] ),
    FILTER ( 'Day_Index', 'Day_Index'[index] - 1 )
)
```

output:

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 110 | 130 |
| 0 | 110 | 130 |

Here Index is coming from Day_Index tables as shown below which is having relation(1 to many) with Fact Table

Day_Index Table:

| Day | Index |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 1 |
| Tuesday | 2 |
| Wednesday | 3 |

Expected result:

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 110 | 130 |
| 0 | 10 | 20 |

Answer (score 0):

Below Dax gives the expected result

```
Delta =
VAR _PrevValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Fact'[Sales] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Day_Column_Index' ),
            Day_Column_Index[Index]
                = MAX ( Day_Column_Index[Index] ) - 1
        )
    )
VAR Result =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _PrevValue ), 0, SUM ( 'Fact'[Sales] ) - _PrevValue ) / 1000
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?